# Writing a function to separate square matrices from a list of matrices in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a function that does as the title says, but keep getting an error. Here is my code:

```py
all_matrices = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G] #these are all matrices defined above

def isSquare(matrices): 
    dims = []
    square_matrices = []
    i = 0

    for i in range(len(matrices)): 
        dims.append(np.shape(matrices[i]))

        if dims[i][0] == dims[i][1]:
            square_matrices.append(matrices[i])   

    return square_matrices
```

Thanks guys for that first answer. Now I have a new problem

I keep getting

> 'tuple index out of range'

but I don't know how to fix this. Any suggestions? I am using the Spyder IDE btw.

Comment: `len(matrices)` will return an `int`. And you cannot iterate `int`. So change your loop to  `for i in range(len(matrices))`

Comment: `for i in len(matrices):` i is an int so is not iterable. `for i in range(len(matrices))` would work as `range` returns an iterable. I guess your `if` statement and return should be indented?

Comment: Yeah, and as @JohnKeyes says, indent your `if`

Comment: It is more pythonic to not use indices at all when iterating over a collection (unless you need the indices themselves for some purpose). You could just use `for matrix in matrices:`. For that matter, you could drop the loop itself and just use a list comprehension (if you have covered those yet).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Even better if you try to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your new problem first - that way you learn the most.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `numpy`, you can do this like the following

```
all_matrices = [np.zeros((3,3)), np.zeros((3,2)), np.zeros((4,4))]

square_matrices = [m for m in all_matrices if m.shape[0] == m.shape[1]]
row_matrices = [m for m in all_matrices if m.shape[0] < m.shape[1]]
col_matrices = [m for m in all_matrices if m.shape[0] > m.shape[1]]
```

Comment: Is there also a way to get row/column matrices using this same method? This is great, thanks!

Comment: What are row/column matrices ?

Comment: On square matrices, dimensions are equal, such as 2x2. Column matrix would be 3x2, row would be 2x3. Not sure why this is useful, just have to do it for an assingment

Comment: Yes, just filter based on the shape of each matrix. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks guys, I figured it out! Once I added the "range" function, I noticed that one of my matrices only had one dimension. That was causing the "out of range" error. I added another dimension and it worked fine. I'm not sure how to do it without adding that dimension though. Thanks

Comment: This should be a comment.